# Откуда взялось фундаментальное определение определителя матрицы?

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Недавно познакомился со следующим определением определителя матрицы (из картинки)
  однако не совсем пойму каким образом он работает, а именно: каким образом можно 
  вообще связать перестановки с геометрической интерпретацией определителя?

Может кто-то знает в какую сторону надо двигаться чтобы дойти до понимания устройства этой формулы, иными словами - мне хотелось бы найти доказательство этого утверждения.

заранее спасибо.

Comment: определитель используется при решении систем уравнений

Comment: Эээ... а что вы понимаете под геометрической интерпретацией определителя?.. И еще - как вы хотите *доказать определение*? В лучшем случае можно доказать *тождественность двух определений*. Какое второе определение определителя? :)

Comment: Геометрическая интерпретация - ориентированный объём N-мерного паралелепипеда

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Есть много способов ввести понятие определителя.

Первый способ - вы его представили в вопросе, по формуле, затем из формулы можно доказывать его свойства.

Второй способ - геометрический, согласно ему определитель это объём паралелепипеда, порождённого векторами-столбцами матрицы, а знак необходимо взять в зависимости от того, является ли набор этих векторов правым или левым. Из такого определения довольно трудно будет вывести свойства.

Третий способ - алгебраический, и он мне нравится больше всех, попробую его изложить.

Рассмотрим квадратную матрицу `A` вещественных чисел, обозначим её столбцы `a_1, ... , a_n`, то есть `a_i` - это вектор-столбец. Все эти векторы являются векторами `n`-мерного пространства (и всего их `n` штук, потому чтот матрица квадратная).

Приступим к определению понятия определителя (его ещё называют детерминантом). Определитель должен сопоставлять матрице `A` вещественное число, то есть это функция `D` на множестве матриц со значением в множестве вещественных чисел.

Как мы только что поняли, матрица это упорядоченный набор `n` векторов `n`-мерного пространства, поэтому определитель это фактически функция `n` переменных, каждая из которых является `n`-мерным вектором: D(a_1, ... , a_n).

Теперь зададим некоторые условия на функцию `D` как требования, а именно - потребуем классических свойств как аксиом (а из этих свойств потом можно будет вывести формулу).

1. Линейность по каждому аргументу (это называется полилинейностью):

   ```
   D(a_1 , ... , x + y , ... a_n) = D(a_1 , ... , x , ... a_n) + D(a_1 , ... , y , ... a_n)
   D(a_1 , ... , h * x , ... , a_n) = h * D(a_1 , ... , x , ... , a_n)
   ```
2. Кососимметричность (если поменять местами два аргумента, то значение изменит знак):

   ```
   D(a_1 , ... , x , ... , y , ... a_n) = -D(a_1 , ... , y , ... , x , ... a_n)
   ```
3. Нормировка (`e_i` далее это единичный вектор, у которого все нули, кроме `i`-й позиции, на которой у него стоит `1`):

   ```
   D(e_1 , ... , e_n) = 1
   ```

Условия 1-2 определяет функцию с точностью до умножения на константу, условие 3 (вместе с условиями 1-2) уже определяет `D` однозначно.

Давайте теперь докажем, что условия 1-3 определяют однозначно функцию `D`, заодно выведем формулу.

Пусть наша матрица `A = (a_ij)`, тогда `a_i = a_i1 * e_1 + ... + a_in * e_n`, подставляем эти выражения в `D`, пользуемся свойством полилинейности, получаем:

```
  D( \sum_j a_1j * e_j , ... , \sum_j a_nj * e_j) = 
= \sum D( a_{i1 j1} * e_{j1} , ... , a_{in jn} * e_{jn} ) = 
= \sum a_{i1 j1} * ... * a_{in jn} * D( e_{j1} , ... , e_{jn} )
```

В последнем выражении стоит сумма по всевозможном комбинациям `i, j, ... , k, l` (всего `2n` индексов), из свойства кососимметричности выводится, что если в наборе присутствует пара одинаковых векторов, то `D = 0`, это значит, что набор "вторых" индексов не должен содержать повторяющиеся, получаем:

```
D(A) = \sum a_{i1 j1} * ... * a{in jn} * D(e_j1 , ... , e_jn)
```

так как среди `j1, ... , jn` нет повторяющихся, отображение индексов `i_k ---> j_k` является перестановкой, значит можно переписать получившуюся сумму так:

```
D(A) = \sum a_{1 s(1)} * ... * a{n s(n)} * D(e_{s(1)} , ... , s(n))
```

Теперь остаётся воспользоваться свойством кососимметричности:

```
D(e_{s(1)} , ... , s(n)) = (-1)^{sgn(s)} * D(e_1 , ... , e_n) = (-1)^{sgn(s)}
```

и получаем требуемую формулу:

```
D(A) = \sum (-1)^{sgn(s)} * a_{1 s(1)} * ... * a{n s(n)}
```

Так как из свойств 1-3 получилась конкретная формула, получается, что они однозначно задают функцию `D`. Также можно убедиться, что функция, задаваемая полученной формулой, удовлетворяет свойствам 1-3, это означает, что формула на самом деле задаёт требуемую функцию.

PS. Для полноты картины, осталось лишь доказать, что эта формула так же даёт ориентированный объём, чтобы получилось, что все три определения эквивалентны. В этом легко убедиться, если заметить, что функция "ориентированный объём" удовлетворяет всем свойствам 1-3, а это значит (по теореме единственности), что она обязана выражаться вышенаписанной формулой.

Comment: теха тут нет, поэтому лучше картинками формулы загружать)

Comment: А нет ли сервиса, куда я запихну текст с теховскими формулами, а он всё автоматом зальёт на хостинг, сгенерит картинки, и на выходе выдаст текст в html (например) формате с уже вставленными картинками? А то вручную всё обрабатывать замучаешься...

Comment: Отличный ответ!